# XCODE - (iOS) Timing / synchronising a view behaving like a slide show to a video

Tags: xcode, ios, video, slideshow, synchronization

This one has been doing my head in for months - So time to swallow my pride and reach out for a little help. At the moment this is being done in UIWebView as HTML5/JS controlled system. But UIWebview frankly sux and looking to make this last component native too.

I have a collection of videos and at specific timed points during the video, I am calling a page of instructions that relate to the timed period in the video. The video controls also act as a controller for the instructions pages. So whatever timed point is reached, the corresponding page is animated into place.

I've looked in many, many options, with the closest coming in with http video streaming and using timed metadata to initiate a view, but I am containing the videos locally on the device. And, as yet cannot find anything that looks like it will work. Seems simple enough in principle, but I'll be damned if I can find a decent solution...

Any ideas / pointers?

Here's the last attempt at going native with this before the remainder of my hair fell out - I think I may be seeing where I was heading in the wrong direction, but if you can spare a few moments, I'd really appreciate it!

OBJECTIVE is to have a shoutOut that lives below the video that contains a page of instructions. At x seconds, the content will be refreshed to correspond to that portion of the video and persist until the next shoutOut for fresh content. This I have managed to achieve successfully. Where I have been falling down (a lot) is when I scrub the video back to a previous section, the shoutOut content remains at the position from which I scrubbed and remains there permanently. Or as the code is below, simply doesn't re-apear as it is set to a timed visible duration.

Anyway, here's the code...

Header:

```
// START:import
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
// START_HIGHLIGHT  
#import <MediaPlayer/MPMoviePlayerController.h>
#import "CommentView.h"
// END_HIGHLIGHT    


// START:def
// START:wiring
@interface MoviePlayerViewController : UIViewController {
    UIView *viewForMovie;
    // END:wiring
    // START_HIGHLIGHT  
    MPMoviePlayerController *player;
    // END_HIGHLIGHT
    // START:wiring
    UILabel *onScreenDisplayLabel;
    UIScrollView *myScrollView;
    NSMutableArray *keyframeTimes;
    NSArray *shoutOutTexts;
    NSArray *shoutOutTimes;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *viewForMovie;
// END:wiring
// START_HIGHLIGHT
@property (nonatomic, retain) MPMoviePlayerController *player;
// END_HIGHLIGHT
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *onScreenDisplayLabel;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *myScrollView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *keyframeTimes;


// START_HIGHLIGHT
-(NSURL *)movieURL;
- (void)timerAction:(NSTimer*)theTimer;
- (void) playerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification;
- (void)handleTapFrom:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
- (IBAction) getInfo:(id)sender;
- (void)removeView:(NSTimer*)theTimer;

// END_HIGHLIGHT
// START:wiring
@end
// END:def
// END:wiring
// END:import
```

Main:

```
@implementation MoviePlayerViewController
// START:synth
@synthesize player;
@synthesize viewForMovie;
@synthesize onScreenDisplayLabel;
@synthesize myScrollView;
@synthesize keyframeTimes;
// END:synth




// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
// START:viewDidLoad
// START:viewDidLoad1
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    keyframeTimes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    shoutOutTexts = [[NSArray 
                      arrayWithObjects:@"This is a test\nLabel at 2 secs ", 
                      @"This is a test\nLabel at 325 secs",
                      nil] retain];
    shoutOutTimes = [[NSArray 
                      arrayWithObjects:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt: 2], 
                      [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt: 325],
                      nil] retain];



    self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
    self.player.contentURL = [self movieURL];
    // END:viewDidLoad1


    self.player.view.frame = self.viewForMovie.bounds;
    self.player.view.autoresizingMask = 
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    [self.viewForMovie addSubview:player.view];
    [self.player play];
    // START_HIGHLIGHT  

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(timerAction:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    // END_HIGHLIGHT    

    // START:viewDidLoad1

    [self.view addSubview:self.myScrollView];


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
     addObserver:self 
     selector:@selector(movieDurationAvailable:)
     name:MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification
     object:nil];
}
// END:viewDidLoad
// END:viewDidLoad1

// START:movieURL
-(NSURL *)movieURL
{
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *moviePath = 
    [bundle 
     pathForResource:@"BigBuckBunny_640x360" 
     ofType:@"m4v"];
    if (moviePath) {
        return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
// END:movieURL

int position = 0;

- (void)timerAction:(NSTimer*)theTimer {
    NSLog(@"hi");
    int count = [shoutOutTimes count];
    NSLog(@"count is at %d", count);

    if (position < count) {
        NSNumber *timeObj = [shoutOutTimes objectAtIndex:position];
        int time = [timeObj intValue];
        NSLog(@"time is at %d", time);
        if (self.player.currentPlaybackTime >= time) {
            CommentView *cview = [[CommentView alloc] 
                                  initWithText:[shoutOutTexts objectAtIndex:position]];
            [self.player.view addSubview:cview];
            position++;
            [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0f target:self selector:@selector(removeView:) userInfo:cview repeats:NO];
        }
    }

}

- (void)removeView:(NSTimer*)theTimer {
    UIView *view = [theTimer userInfo];
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}
/*
 // Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 }
 */

// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void) movieDurationAvailable:(NSNotification*)notification {
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [notification object];
    int duration = [moviePlayer duration];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
     addObserver:self 
     selector:@selector(playerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinish:)
     name:MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinishNotification
     object:nil];

    NSMutableArray *times = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        [times addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5+i*((duration)/20)]];
    }
    [self.player requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:times timeOption: MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
}

int p = 0;
int ll=0;
- (void) playerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {


    NSDictionary *userInfo;
    userInfo = [notification userInfo];

    NSNumber *timecode;
    timecode = [userInfo objectForKey: @"MPMoviePlayerThumbnailTimeKey"];


    [keyframeTimes addObject: timecode];

    UIImage *image;
    image = [userInfo objectForKey: @"MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageKey"];

    int width = image.size.width;
    int height = image.size.height;
    float newwidth = 75 * ((float)width / (float)height);


    self.myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake((newwidth + 2) * 20, 75);

    UIImageView *imgv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [imgv setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    [imgv setFrame:CGRectMake(ll, 0, newwidth, 75.0f)];
    ll+=newwidth + 2;



    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                             initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapFrom:)];
    [tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];

    [imgv addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
    [tapRecognizer release];


    [myScrollView addSubview:imgv];

}

- (void) getInfo:(id)sender
{
    MPMovieMediaTypeMask mask = self.player.movieMediaTypes;
    NSMutableString *mediaTypes = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    if (mask == MPMovieMediaTypeMaskNone) {
        [mediaTypes appendString:@"Unknown Media Type"];
    } else {
        if (mask & MPMovieMediaTypeMaskAudio) {
            [mediaTypes appendString:@"Audio"];
        }       
        if (mask & MPMovieMediaTypeMaskVideo) {
            [mediaTypes appendString:@"Video"];
        }

    }

    MPMovieSourceType type = self.player.movieSourceType;
    NSMutableString *sourceType = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];
    if (type == MPMovieSourceTypeUnknown) {
        [sourceType appendString:@"Source Unknown"];
    } else if (type == MPMovieSourceTypeFile) {
        [sourceType appendString:@"File"];
    } else if (type == MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming) {
        [sourceType appendString:@"Streaming"];
    }           


    CGSize size = self.player.naturalSize;

    onScreenDisplayLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[Type: %@] [Source: %@] [Time: %.1f of %.f secs] [Playback: %.0fx] [Size: %.0fx%.0f]", 
                                 mediaTypes,
                                 sourceType,
                                 self.player.currentPlaybackTime, 
                                 self.player.duration,
                                 self.player.currentPlaybackRate,
                                 size.width,
                                 size.height];
}

- (void)handleTapFrom:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    NSArray *subviews = [myScrollView subviews];
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        if (recognizer.view == [subviews objectAtIndex:i]) {
            NSNumber *num = [keyframeTimes objectAtIndex:i];
            self.player.currentPlaybackTime = [num intValue];
            return;
        }
    }

}

@end
```

The Comment View Header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface CommentView : UIView {

}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andText:(NSString *) text;
- (id)initWithText:(NSString *) text;

@end
```

The Comment View Main:

```
#import "CommentView.h"


@implementation CommentView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andText:(NSString *) text {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"comment.png"];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        [self addSubview:imageView];

        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(20, 20, 200.0f, 90.0f);
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
        label.text = text;
        label.numberOfLines = 3;
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self addSubview:label];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithText:(NSString *) text {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"comment.png"];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        [self addSubview:imageView];

        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(20, 20, 200.0f, 90.0f);
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
        label.text = text;
        label.numberOfLines = 3;
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self addSubview:label];
    }
    return self;
}



- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Thoughts anyone?

Cheers!

Comment: I can see in the log that the timer is continuing after I have paused the video so I obviously need to hook that up somehow. Then I can worry about using views instead just text and background images - I think...

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with monitoring `currentPlaybackTime` at regular intervals (assuming you are using an instance that implements `MPMediaPlayback` for playback).

Comment: I looked in to that as it seemed the most obvious route to follow. I managed to get it to produce callouts but could not figure out how to link the events to another subview that I could use as the equivalent of a slide show.

Comment: You should have mentioned all that in your question. You should edit it now to tell us in detail (incl. code) what you did and how it failed. Then ask us a specific question. We're not here to read your mind.

Comment: Fair and valid point... I'll revisit and try to be more specific.